# Javascript method chaining

Tags: javascript

Didn't know how else to put this.

Say I have a JavaScript method that makes some AJAX calls:

```
function makeAJAXCalls()
{
    // who knows how long this will take
}
```

And I don't want the next function to execute until all the AJAX calls are complete. I also don't want to put the next function call into the success callback for the AJAX call.

Is there a way I can like chain these, so the next function doesn't get called until `makeAJAXCalls()` is done everything it needs to do?

Comment: why dont you want to put it into the success? thats how callbacks work

Comment: Synchronous calls? I wouldn't advise it though.

Comment: Because I don't want it to get called every time the AJAX method is called, only when I specify it.

Comment: Well then, only specify a callback when you need to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var queueCount =0;
function makeAjaxCalls()
{
    queueCount+=7; // or however many calls you need to make.
    // make your ajax calls. onSuccess (or failure), call checkQueue();
}
function checkQueue()
{
    queueCount--;
    if (queueCount <=0)
    {
       doNext();
    }
}
```

This leaves the calls asynchronous, which may be the intent here.

Comment: Thanks.  We would consider this a classic approach.  Although I love jquery, sometimes it is just easier to solve the problem through simple means.

Answer (score 3):

You could use jQuery's `$.when()` [functionality](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/).

```
$.when(makeAjaxCalls()).done(function () { 
   // Do other things here 
});
```

You can even add multiple functions to the when if you wanted all of those to be completed first. These are all called [Deferred Objects](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/).

Comment: This is very interesting. Does it call as soon as I make that bind or is it binded to the AJAX function and only gets called when the AJAX function is called?

Comment: The done part will only fire once the function is completely finished.

Comment: This will only work if `makeAjaxCalls` returns deferred objects.

Comment: @mike but if the makeAjaxCalls fires the ajax requests, does done wait until all responses are completed, or does it just fire when the makeAjaxCalls method exits?  Those are two very different things....

Comment: @Matt very true... I am assuming that it does :) @hvgotcodes Good question, I will test it

Comment: That's really not a safe assumption, given the OP's apparent lack of awareness of deferred objects.

Comment: For general reference... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4866721/what-are-deferred-objects

Answer (score 1):

You are really limiting your options. AJAX is asynchronous by nature (unless you use synchronized xhrs, which you don't want because they freeze the browser).  So your only option is to handle it in the callback, because the callbacks are the only way you know the request has completed, and where the data from the requests gets passed when they complete.

Because you have multiple callbacks, and you want to wait till they are all done, you can put the same function call in all the callbacks, and that function can track which responses have come back, and only proceed if all responses are there.

so you can do something like

```
var resultsHolder = [];
var syncer = function(response){
    // add results to resultsHolder on call

    if (resultsHolder.lengh === numberExpected) {
     //proceed
    }
}
```

then use syncer in your makeAllRequests method

Answer (score 1):

You could, by making your calls synchronous.

[Example: Synchronous request](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Example.3a.c2.a0Synchronous_request)

Although you might want to take note that this will probably cause an undesired blocking effect on the rest of your application that might call into question the reason for using synchronous xhr.

Comment: @SLaks I completely agree, but it is a possibility none the less.

Answer (score 1):

You can make chained ajax calls if you're using jQuery 1.5+. This works because `$.ajax()` returns a [`jqXHR`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) which is also a [Deferred Object](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object).

```
function makeAjaxCalls()
{
    return $.ajax(/* snip options */);
}

function handleSuccess(data)
{
    // do something with the data
}

function nextAjax()
{
    return $.ajax(/* snip other options */);
}

// then...
makeAjaxCalls().success(handleSuccess).complete(nextAjax);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should take your own callback as a parameter to the function.
This way, the caller can decide what to do next.

You could also return a `Deferred` object.