# Force code to execute after another method finishes executing

Tags: javascript

Here is what I want to do:

setSource is a function which executes about 3 seconds.

```
 editor.setSource();

 setTimeout(function () {
      //do something, some commands
 }, 3000);
```

I want the //do something, some commands part to be executed AFTER the last line of setSource() is executed. Now I'm doing it with setTimeout, but I think it's not very good solution, because sometimes setSource() will take maybe 5 seconds to execute. How to do this?

Comment: Can you use jquery? They have deferred objects which does this easily. If not you could make your own callback

Comment: Meaning, pass the function in as a variable and then run it at the end of the function, passing variables into it as needed. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2190850/create-a-custom-callback-in-javascript

Comment: @JeffShaver Yes I can use jquery.

Comment: You can refer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4866721/what-are-deferred-objects

Comment: Deferred Objects: http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have `setSource` take a callback argument:

```
editor.setSource = function(callback) {
    // do editor things
    callback();
}
```

Then pass the next block of code to be executed as a callback:

```
editor.setSource(function() {
    // do some other things
});
```

---

If you have access to jQuery's deferred objects, you can make use of them here:

1. Make a new deferred object.
2. Start the timeout to do your long task.
3. Return the deferred object.
4. In the timeout, once the task is complete, call `deferred.resolve`.

```
editor = {
    setSource: function() {
        var deferred = $.Deferred();

        console.log("Beginning editor.setSource...");

        setTimeout(function() {
            // This function took a while to occur
            deferred.resolve();
        }, 3000);

        return deferred;
    }
}

$.when(editor.setSource()).then(function() {
    console.log("Editor is done!");
});
```

If you're doing AJAX or animation or another jQuery task that uses deferred objects already, you can just return its result value instead of making your own deferred object:

```
editor = {
    setSource: function() {
        return $.get({
            url: "myurl.com/mypage",
            data: $("#myform").serialize()
        });
    }
}

$.when(editor.setSource()).then(function() {
    console.log("Editor is done!");
});
```

Make sure to look up how you can either *resolve* or *reject* deferred objects, and how to handle those.

Comment: No reason for the setTimeout if he is going to use callbacks

Comment: @JeffShaver I assume he had something that took 3 seconds, which is what I'm pretending exists.

Comment: He was currently using the setTimeout in place of callbacks

Comment: @JeffShaver I assumed he had some asynchronous task in his `setSource` function, so I further assumed that it was a `setTimeout` call or something.

Answer (score 3):

### This answer uses [`promises`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), a JavaScript feature of the `ECMAScript 6` standard. If your target platform does not support `promises`, polyfill it with [PromiseJs](https://www.promisejs.org/).

In newer browser versions you can use `ES6 promises`. `editor.setSource()` wraps its execution into a `Promise` and returns it, so it can be continued with other functions.

```
editor.setSource = function(){
    return new Promise(function(fulfill, reject){
        //do your work
        fulfill(resultValue);
    });
};
```

To continue it with another function simply use the `then` method on the promise.

```
var promise = editor.setSource();
promise.then(function(result){
    //do something more
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also looking for solution where I want to execute my second function only after previous function gets executed completely, I tried callback function but still not getting the solution, finally I find the very easiest way to resolve this issue by using simple `$.ajax({ });` method code which works for me :).

for example,

```js
$.ajax({
  url: function1(),
  success: function(){
    //function 2 code here or just call function2() here
  }
});
```

that's all, in this code url parameter will call first function and only on the success of its execution function 2 will be called.